# footer always at the bottom; background image for contents and footer

Tags: html, css

My html page has a title and a menu at the top, the contents section under the menu, and the footer at the bottom. The footer must always be at the bottom of the window, no matter what the content size is (except for when the content if higher than the window, in which case the footer must be underneath the content). I have markup and CSS rules that implement this (below).

But I need to also show a background image over the contents and the footer. That is, the image must cover the entire screen but the title/menu area. I have no idea how to accomplish this. In my code below (as well as on jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/EGj54/) I have attached the background to the whole page, but I want it to show only for the contents and the footer.

Could someone help me please?

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="navbar">
        <div id="caption"><span>Test</span></div>
        <ul id="sections">
            <li><span>current</span></li>
            <li><a href="">next</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">content</div>
    <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>

* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul li {
    display: inline;
}
#caption {
    font-weight: bold;
}
#footer, .push {
    color: white;
    height: 25px;
}
#sections {
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
}
#main {
    height: auto !important;
    margin: 0 auto -25px; /* bottom margin is negative value of #footer height */
    min-height: 100%;
}
#main {
    background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/Clouds_over_the_Atlantic_Ocean.jpg/800px-Clouds_over_the_Atlantic_Ocean.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `background-position` of the image

```
#main {
    background-image: url('yourimage.jpg');
    background-size: cover;

    background-position: 0 100px; // 100px or whatever the height of your navbar is
}
```

Alternatively, You can cheat like this ;)

```
#content {
    height: 100px;
    background: url('yourimage.jpg') top;
}
#footer {
    height: 50px;
    background: url('yourimage.jpg') bottom;
}
```

Comment: I do not know the height of the navbar, and also if I set position, it will clip the bottom of the image. I need the image to cover the area.

Comment: Do you think the alternative method could be useful?

Answer (score 0):

Your footer will stay at the bottom since you placed it last with your divs, no problem with that as long as you will not use `float` or absolute positioning. Move your style in background to `body` to solve your problem:

```
body {
    background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/Clouds_over_the_Atlantic_Ocean.jpg/800px-Clouds_over_the_Atlantic_Ocean.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: or if you do not want to apply it to whole body, create another div parent then paste all that mark-ups in that new div then assign the background style with that new div.

Comment: your concern is to still have the background image seen beneath the footer right? Have you tried it? Footer is outside `#main` so that would make it outside the background image

Comment: I want to have an image covering the entire screen but the menu and the title part.

Answer (score 0):

can you simply adjust the vertical position of the background images?

```
background-position: left 20px;
```